# How to use a custom location for messages properties files in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Im using thymeleaf and spring, my messages.properties files need to have the same name as the template in order for them to work. I have tried to create a custom path using webConfigurer.Java but it's not working.

WebConfigurer.java source:

```
...
...
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"en.irp.project.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@Import({SecurityConfigurer.class})
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @Bean(name="messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("WEB-INF/languages/messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return localeResolver;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the full path of your `WEB-INF` folder from your `src` folder?

Answer (score 10):

Just for future reference.

If **Spring Boot** is used, you can also set its custom location in *application.properties* file:

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

Javadoc:

> Comma-separated list of basenames, each following the ResourceBundle
>   convention. Essentially a fully-qualified classpath location. If it
>   doesn't contain a package qualifier (such as "org.mypackage"), it will
>   be resolved from the classpath root.

Answer (score 3):

The idea that messages.properties files need to have the same name as the template is not very common. However you can solve this by listen all your files in the configuration.
          `messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/template1","classpath:i18n/template2"...);`

if you put them into the classpath or in replace `classpath:i18n` by `WEB-INF/languages`.
Perhaps you can create the list of basenames via program logic. 
Have in mind, that even with this approach a message-key could only defined once in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I got it work as follows.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{       
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames( "file:" + System.getProperty( "web.server.message" ), "/WEB-INF/languages/messages" );
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding( CHARACTER_ENCODING );
    return messageSource;
}
```

Here I wanted to use different set of messages files in DEV mode, so I used a system property in pom.xml for message file path. My messages files are in this format :     messages_en.properties under the languages folder.

```
<systemProperties>                    
     <web.server.message>${basedir}/src/main/resources/conf/languages/messages</web.server.message>
</systemProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties file, just mention the value for spring.messages.baseDir.

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    List<String> baseNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String baseName = applicationProperties.getString("spring.messages.basename", DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BASENAME);
    String messageResourcePath = applicationProperties.getString("spring.messages.baseDir");
    if(isNotEmpty(messageResourcePath)){
        baseNames.add(String.format("file:%s", Paths.get(messageResourcePath, baseName)));
    }
    baseNames.add(String.format("classpath:%s", baseName));
    resource.setBasenames(baseNames.toArray(new String[baseNames.size()]));
    String encoding = applicationProperties.getString("spring.messages.encoding", CHARACTER_ENCODING);
    LOGGER.debug("Encoding is set to :: {}", encoding);
    resource.setDefaultEncoding(encoding);
    resource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return resource;
}
```